# very simple but can't resolve. grabbing element

Tags: javascript, dom

i'm trying to get the value from the ID => vname into the variable *name*

and the return should be "Loren", 
I tried with and without the value attribute call but doesn't work.  what am i missing?

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
var name = document.getElementById("vname").value;


alert(name);


</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="vname" value="firstname">Loren</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put `<script></script>` after `p` element or wrap your js in`window.onload = function(){ <...> }`

Comment: Please provide a more meaningful title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three things wrong here:

- You are trying to access the element before it exists You cannot eat the pizza before it is delivered... See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196) for more info.
- `<p>` HTML elements do not have a `value` attribute. In your case, `value` is a non-standard HTML attribute. If you want to use custom attributes, use [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) instead.
- `p` DOM elements do not have a `value` property. Only form control elements (`input`, `select`, etc) have such a property. If you want to get the **content** of an element, use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) or [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead.

---

If you had opened your browser's console, you would have seen an error, because the element with ID `vname` couldn't be found. Make yourself familiar with your browser's developer tools so that you can fix issues like this on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the "value" of a p element, you have to get the "innerHTML"

try this: `var name = document.getElementById("vname").innerHTML;`

Answer (score 0):

Try var name = document.getElementById("vname").innerHTML;

Answer (score 0):

When you try to access the `#vname` is not in the DOM yet. You will need to add the script tag after the element or wait for the DOM to be loaded.

When that is said a `<p>` tag cannot have a value. Use `data-value` instead:

```
<p id="vname" data-value="firstname">Loren</p>
<script>
  var vname = document.getElementById("vname");
  var value = vname.getAttribute('data-value');
  console.log(value);
</script>
```